# Java Iterate through arraylist of date objects and convert each date to its unix time stamp

Tags: java, loops, date, unix

I have an array list of date objects that I would like to convert into Unix time stamps of each date. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java 8+, you could stream the `List` and map the time from [`Date.getTime()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime--) to the timestamp by dividing by 1000 (since unix timestamp is expressed in seconds since epoch, while the Java timestamp is in milliseconds since epoch). Then collect it to a `List<Long>` like

```
List<Date> dates = new ArrayList<>();
// ...
List<Long> unixTimeStamps = dates.stream()
        .mapToLong(x -> x.getTime() / 1000).boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) class have a method [`getTime()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), which retrieves the milliseconds since Jan 1, 1970. You can use this method and simply divide it by 1000 to get the [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

```
List<Date> dates = new ArrayList<>();

//...
//populate `date` using suitable logic
//...

List<Long> unixTS = new ArrayList<>();
for(Date date : dates) {
    unixTS.add(date.getTime()/1000);
}
```